# How is double-spending technically prevented in traditional banking?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, payment

In contrast to bitcoin:
How is double-spending **technically** prevented in traditional banking? Do database transactions have to conform to the **ACID** property in order to prevent double-spending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible ways:

1. If the database manager supports true SERIALIZABLE isolation level, it means transactions appear to execute in some serial order. So if you select the account in which balance is to be deducted, you can check if it would become negative. If not, transfer the funds. There is no race condition because the SERIALIZABLE isolation level guarantees everything in all transactions appears to execute in some serial order. There are optimistic and pessimistic SERIALIZABLE strategies. Optimistic cancels the transaction if serialization violation would occur, pessimistic uses locking.
2. If no support for SERIALIZABLE isolation level, you can lock the two accounts (preferably lowest-numbered first to prevent deadlocks), then check balance, then transfer funds, and now no race conditions can occur due to locking.

It's a centralized consistent database. Very similar to Bitcoin, although Bitcoin manages to create a consistent database in a distributed manner.

Answer (score 0):

Event-based systems lead to full serializability of transactions with respect to one account.

Yes, using ACID databases is entirely sensible. By using a suitable transaction isolation level, issues like double-spend can be prevented.

However, banks need to keep logs of everything. So the source of truth will not be a “current account value” record in a database, but an event stream of all transactions that affected an account. For example, we might have events affecting one account like:

```
time  id       event
----- -------- -----
08:01 df28f233 TransferIn($200, from=acc1234)
08:02 2d78f708 TransferIn($700, from=acc3412)
08:39 ea3fc9a2 TransferOut($150, to=acc=6789, within=2 business day)
08:42 a4ca1ed2 TransferOut($600, to=acc9087, within=2 business days)
10:13 5a42f172 Revert(2d78f708, reason=fraud)
10:13 c65a4bce Revert(a4ca1ed2, reason=insufficient funds)
19:36 28638b2d Settle(ea3fc9a2)
```

Using this event log, the events can be replayed at any time to check the books and to settle transactions with other institutions.

Depending on where you are in the world, banks might also not settle transactions immediately. They might collect pending transactions during the business day, and then settle them after hours, when no further transactions will be accepted. If you will, this could be interpreted as a kind of highly-regulated eventual consistency approach. The bank will likely keep track of a current account value, and will do that using ACID transactions, but the main value of that would be to prevent transactions that would be reverted later. Transactions that are never settled also have some interesting use cases, for example for authorizing an amount on a credit card as a security deposit for a hotel room or rental car.

Comment: *"an event stream of all transactions that affected an account"* - even banks with the most generous complement of storage capacity, do not keep all transactions from the inception of the account. As for "authorised amounts" on credit cards, these are generally handled not formally as transactions, but in a shadow system of earmarks or reservations against the credit limit or account balance. (1/2)

Comment: Most credit card systems trace their design back to the days of carbon paper - very large purchases could be checked with the bank first by phone or machine, but there was little to stop cardholders blowing through their limit with many smaller unchecked transactions in a short period. There used to be a flag which told merchants (or ATM machines) to withhold the card on presentation - prior to that, there was probably an "all points bulletin" of prolific abusers sent to merchants who accepted cards. (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

Traditional banking is based on traditional accountancy, where all journal entries identify at least two accounts, and debits and credits must balance to zero.

The most basic way in which consistency is checked, is by constantly checking the balance of the system, typically once a working day. Because the balancing is done every day, the scope for investigating error is typically no wider than that day's transactions.

There is also regular external reconciliation. For example, counting the cash, and ensuring that the physical amount on hand, matches the amount the accounting system says should be on hand.

Some of the earliest commercial applications of computers were in banking. I believe this began in the early 60s, predating even the theory of relational databases (EF Codd, 1970).

But it is not that difficult to design algorithms that perform accountancy work correctly, provided the computer itself is working correctly, and there were database technologies that preceded relational databases.

In terms of computer error, banks originally produced and maintained paper records for as long as necessary to cover any processing done by computer. This is part of the reason why, even until relatively recently, most transactions done at a bank were covered by a paper slip of some sort, the details on which were then entered into the computer terminal, and the slip retained in the drawer until at least the end of the day.

If the computer defected somehow, and if it didn't balance when correct operation resumed, the bank staff would verify everything from the last time the system was known to have correctly balanced (probably the evening of the previous working day), and the primary paper records made since.

In the distant past, the computer would not usually have retained a long account history. Old records no longer relevant to processing, would be either regularly printed out, or photographed to microfiche, for archiving. As well as a paper statement being sent to the customer, of course, which if it's contents weren't queried promptly, would be forever binding once the bank purged old records.

It's worth mentioning in passing that the main site of data processing in most banks, used to be the branch. Each branch would originally have had a large staff, and later its own computer, and this could operate more or less autonomously in serving the local community. Only summary figures were reported centrally.

This is why to be a "bank manager" was originally a position of considerable trust and status, because although they would be unlikely to get away with something as fundamental as having unbalanced books, they had considerable latitude and final authority over most matters (including overseeing that the cash physically on hand in the safe, matched what the books said, and that recorded variances were within acceptable limits!).

I don't know how withdrawals were traditionally handled at a different branch than the one where the account was kept. Probably by one bank manager ringing the other bank manager, and each making the necessary account entries before the end of the phone call.

In summary, you can see that for core banking operations, the main guarantees of consistency are provided by the standard methods of accountancy itself, not by any particular computer technology.